# Python 3.4 - updating null values when combing csv (if there is an update)

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, python-3.4

I have written some early code to combine all .xls files in a folder into one csv. I want to run this program once a week to combine all the daily updated .xls reports together.

My problem is some fields are null until a later spreadsheet fill in the item. For example

```
Spreadsheet from 24th     Spreadsheet from 28th

Repaired Status           Repaired Status 
Abuse                     Abuse
NFF                       NFF
(null)                    Abuse
NFF                       NFF
Abuse                     Abuse
(null)                    Abuse
```

I thought maybe i should add each spreadsheet filename to a list when its added to csv, then ignore that file next time program  runs, then the newest file would overwrite data from the last one. Not sure if this would work or how to do it?

Will the above work or is there another way i can do this?

Edit: As i have had no response, I decided to just not update the row if it had null values, this makes my data is out of date but accurate,

Would still love to hear if anyone knows a way to achieve my question. Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact question? What is not working in the code above?

Comment: The code above works correctly, my questions is, if i want to add a csv that has updates to data from a previously added csv, can i do it reliably? (as per the example in original text)